# Как использовать несколько configmap в Spring Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes

Я пытаюсь создать микросервисную архитектуру на Spring с деплоем в Kubernetes
У части сервисов дублируются настройки, поэтому логично вынести повторяющиеся настройки в отдельные ConfigMap
Чтобы читать ConfigMap я использую Spring Cloud Kubernetes config
Вот его зависимость (maven):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Вот мой файл bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapp
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        namespace: dev
        name: globalconfig
        sources:
          - name: localconfig
          - name: dbconfig
          - name: queueconfig
```

Вот так, к примеру, выглядит файл QueueConfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: queueconfig
  namespace: dev
data:
  application.yml: |-
    messaging:
      queues:
        new-messages-queue: new
```

А вот так выглядит файл localconfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: localconfig
  namespace: dev
data:
  application.yml: |-
    file:
      name:
        new-file: process
```

Моё приложение не видит настройки, может быть дело в том, что получется так, что у приложения несколько конфигурационных файлов yml?

Мой deployment выглядит следующим образом:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
  namespace: dev
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: app
          resources: { }
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: database.url
                  name: endpoints
            - name: RABBIT_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: rabbit.host
                  name: endpoints
            - name: RABBIT_PORT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: rabbit.port
                  name: endpoints
            - name: SQS_ENDPOINT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: sqs.url
                  name: endpoints
            - name: SQS_REGION
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: sqs.region
                  name: endpoints
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: database.user
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: DB_SCHEMA_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: database.schema
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: RABBIT_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: rabbit.user
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: RABBIT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: rabbit.password
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: AWS_ACCESS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: aws.access
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: AWS_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: aws.secret
                  name: umtapsecrets
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: database.password
                  name: umtapsecrets
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: { }
      serviceAccountName: configmap-viewer
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Comment: покажите deployment вашего приложения в кубер

Comment: @SeniorPomidor добавил deployment

Comment: приложение не видит настройки. потому что настройки ссылаются к `endpoints` конфигу, а не те, что вы указали.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor endpoints - не конфиг, а секрет
Дело совсем не в этом, в Endpoints приложение обращается за ENV
Дело не в этом